# Models validation on test set

Tags: cross-validation, model-evaluation

I have trained two different models (an ANN and an SVR) on the same training set, using K-fold CV. 
I would like to know if I have to evaluate their performance exactly on the same test set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not evaluate their performance on the test set. If you use test set results to select the best model, you are fitting that choice parameter to the test set. And then how do you test *that* choice?

Instead, choose between the two models with cross-validation. If they are close in performance, you may also want to try ensembling them. Then try the final model on the test set to get an idea of out-of-sample performance. But after you get those results, you shouldn't be making any more choices about your model based on them.